# Python 3.5 syntax using '@' to pass argument into function and PyLint

Tags: python, python-3.5, pylint

I'm currently using the PySpice module for circuit sim. PySpice is using some syntax implemented in Python 3.5 that I've never seen before: https://pyspice.fabrice-salvaire.fr/api/PySpice/Unit.html I'd like to find the Python reference for this syntax.

Primarily, I'd like to get PyLint to recognize it.

Comment: This is merely the new matrix multiplication operator. It actually doesn't have any built in implementation, rather, it was added for scientific computing libraries like `numpy` to distinguish matrix multiplication from other types.

Comment: Are you running PyLint on Python 3.5? Have you updated PyLint? It should recognize the syntax.

Comment: I'm on the latest version, Python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

That's the [matrix multiplication operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html?highlight=matrix%20multiplication#whatsnew-pep-465). You can override it with `__matmul__` or `__rmatmul__`.

Comment: I saw that it's used as a matrix multiplication operator. Assumed it was being used to pass an argument into a function. Guess I'm going to read the source code now to see how its implemented.